# I need to get the like_count from_like info

Tags: javascript, facebook-fql

I have FQL code in javascript

```
SELECT caption,src_small,like_info from photo where object_id="123456789"
```

which outputs

```
{  "data": [   {
  "caption": "the caption", 
  "src_small": "theimageurl.jpg", 
  "like_info": {
    "can_like": true, 
    "like_count": 'thenumberoflikes', 
    "user_likes": true }}]}
```

this is the javascript:

```
query.wait(function(rows) {
                   document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML =  


                    '<img src="' +  rows[0].src_small + '" alt="" />' + "<br />"+
                     'Name: '+  rows[0].caption+ "<br />"+
                    *// 'Number of likes: '      +  rows[0].like_info.cells[0].like_count+ "<br />" ;*

                 });
```

Now I don't know how to get the like count it returns undefined, anybody knows how to get the like_count or the cells part only the rows.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works to access your data:

```
//Get like_count:
obj["data"][0].like_info.like_count
```

Because the object that is returned is structured as follows:

```
var obj = { "data": [
    {
        "caption": "the caption",
        "src_small": "theimageurl.jpg",
        "like_info": {
            "can_like": true,
            "like_count": 'thenumberoflikes',
            "user_likes": true
        }
    }
    ],[
    {
        "caption": "The second object!",
        "src_small": "theimageurl.jpg",
        "like_info": {
            "can_like": true,
            "like_count": 'thenumberoflikes',
            "user_likes": true
        }
    }
    ]
};
```

the `[0]` is referring to the first object in the result. To get the `user_likes` of the second object, you'd use:

```
obj["data"][1].like_info.user_likes
```

in your case, you will probably have to replace `obj["data"]` with `rows`

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I got it I just need the .like_count
This is the last line
   'Number of likes: '      +  rows[0].like_info.like_count+ "<br />" ;
Thanks Cerbrus! :)